# Slider em jQuery (Nivo Slider) não funciona quando está dentro de um conteúdo carregado via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, slider

Estou utilizando o plugin Nivo Slider para criar um slider na minha página. Se eu colocar a estrutura do slider diretamente na página, ele carrega certinho... mas se estiver dentro de um conteúdo carregado via ajax, simplesmente não aparece nada.

O que pode ser? O engraçado é que o lighbox funciona, mas o slider não...

Eu uso isso pra carregar o slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
</script>
```

E é assim que eu chamo meu conteúdo ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function startEmpreendimento(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var href = "<?php echo $primeiroID; ?>";
           $("#content-empreendimentos").load(href + " #content-empreendimentos");
        }           
       window.onload=startEmpreendimento;
```

Comment: Não sei se vai resolver seu problema, mas eu já passei por algo parecido. Me disseram que o carregamento Ajax não carrega os scripts Jquery, então uma possível solução é você colocar os scripts no carregamento da pagina inicial (Pelo menos comigo funciono)

Comment: pois é, o grande problema é justamente esse: eu carrego TUDO na página inicial, dentro do ajax está somente a div com o conteúdo do slider... se eu coloco a mesmíssima div do slider FORA do carregamento via ajax, ou seja, diretamente na index, tudo corre bem.

Comment: Você usa o WAMP SERVER?

Comment: Não, localmente desenvolvo com o xampp.

Comment: ta aqui um projeto meu que uso lightbox e carregamento ajax, talvez te ajude. A pagina INDEX ta com o carregamento ajax e o lightbox e a pagina WMIN é carregada, olha os scripts de carregamento ajax, talvez te ajude.. http://www.4shared.com/rar/lwgAYTvqba/projeto01.html

Answer (score 1):

Coloca a instância do slide após o carregamento do ajax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<!-- Adicione todos os importes necessários -->
<script src="js/ideal-image-slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // Essa função será executada quando a página carregar
      var href = "<?php echo $primeiroID; ?>";

      $("#content-empreendimentos").load(href + " #content-empreendimentos", function(){
         // Esse código será executado quando o load terminar
         $('#slider').nivoSlider();
      });

   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="slider">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ex7POmy4uKpK15UGrnuV?p=preview)**

Comment: Kadu, acho que é quase isso, mas em algum lugar, faltou adicionar o src do arquivo js/ideal-image-slider.js

Comment: Ele não está adicionado no `head` da sua página, `<script src="js/ideal-image-slider.js"></script>`?

Comment: Antes ele dava o load direto na função, mas coloquei no head e não resolveu... quando usso esse código aí, até mesmo o que funcionava na home (fora do conteúdo ajax), para de funcionar :(

Comment: Atualizei o código ali, se mesmo assim não estiver conseguindo, coloque seu código no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) pra gente ver o que está acontecendo de errado...

Comment: Então, agora com esse novo código, o slider que coloquei de teste na Homepage (sem o ajax) funciona normalmente... mas infelizmente, o que vem carregado junto com o conteúdo ajax continua a não funcionar...

Acho que existe alguma treta entre Ajax vs Jquery que deve ser resolvida com algum tipo de gambiarra, como o tal do 'Delegate' que o Ricardo postou acima... o problema é que eu não tenho nem ideia de como usar isso :(

Comment: Coloquei um link para demo ali, da uma olhada e qualquer coisa se mesmo assim não conseguir crie um com seu código pra ver oque está acontecendo...

Comment: Então... isso aí eu consegui fazer, colocar o slider pra funcionar na home. O problema ocorre apenas quando carrego o conteúdo onde vem o slider via ajax. Tente fazer o seguinte: Substitui o conteúdo

    '<div class="entry-content">
      <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
         <div class="ribbon"></div>
         <div id="nivoslider" class="nivoSlider"></div>
      </div>'

por: '<div id="ajaxLoader"></div>'

Depois, mande carregar o conteúdo substituído ali dentro via ajax. É isso o que acontece comigo. Se ele estiver puro, na home, funfa legal. Se vier via ajax, não funciona.

Comment: Fiz e funcionou.... **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ex7POmy4uKpK15UGrnuV?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Brother, o DOM  é dinâmico, lembre-se disso sempre.
Você precisa acionar o nivoslider somente após carregado o conteúdo em sua div... Alí, onde está, você está dizendo ao jquery, ao terminar de carregar a página, faça isso com esse div, e não é isso que você quer.

Você quer que quando o div for carregado com seus objetos vindos do ajax será acionado o nivoslider.

Answer (score -1):

Creio que precisas de utilizar o delegate: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
Já me aconteceu outras vezes, mas com o click, que depois de carregar uma página via AJAX ele deixava de funcionar...

Comment: Obrigado camarada, vou estudar essa possibilidade também e, se funcionar, posto aqui.

Edit: dei uma olhada mas, ainda sou muito iniciante no que diz respeito à dev... o que exatamente eu faria com esse 'delegate'?

Comment: De notar que eu nunca usei o nivoSlider (por isso não sei se isto vai funcionar, mas onde tens:
$('#slider').nivoSlider();
tenta meter
$("#content-empreendimentos").delegate("#slider", "nivoSlider");

Como disse nunca trabalhei com o nivoSlider, por isso não sei se isso vai funcionar!

Comment: É, continua não funcionando... com este código aí, até na Home para de funcionar :(